# AWS SAM StepFunctionsExecutionPolicy error: not authorized to perform: states:StartExecution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions, aws-sam

Trying to use [StepFunctionsExecutionPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-template-list.html#stepfunctions-execution-policy) to call one [nested AWS SFN workflow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-nested-workflows.html) this way:

```
Resources:
  SubProcessStateMachine:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
    Properties:
      DefinitionUri: statemachine/subproces.asl.json
      DefinitionSubstitutions:
        ...
      Policies:
        - LambdaInvokePolicy:
            FunctionName: !Ref Step1Function
        - LambdaInvokePolicy:
            FunctionName: !Ref Step2Function
        ...

Resources:
  MainProcessStateMachine:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
    Properties:
      DefinitionUri: statemachine/mainprocess.asl.json
      DefinitionSubstitutions:
        SubProcessStateMachineArn: !GetAtt SubProcessStateMachine.Arn
      Policies:
        - LambdaInvokePolicy:
            FunctionName: !Ref MainStep1Function
        - LambdaInvokePolicy:
            FunctionName: !Ref MainStep2Function
        - DynamoDBWritePolicy:
            TableName: !Ref TransactionTable
        - StepFunctionsExecutionPolicy:
            StateMachineName: !Ref SubProcessStateMachine
```

Results in the following deployment error:

```
{
  "error": "StepFunctions.AWSStepFunctionsException",
  "cause": "User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/test-stack-MainProcessStateMachineRole-1CH1LCY04D45W/seocvrGPXAHUDBGeYcGgtAlqbcmXAHnC 
   is not authorized to perform: states:StartExecution on resource: arn:aws:states:eu-central-1:123456789:stateMachine:SubProcessStateMachine-kotNR6COw7mh 
  (Service: AWSStepFunctions; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 64701c03-207e-423d-94c4-d63e0aa22027; Proxy: null)"
}
```

What is wrong with the CloudFormation template ?

Answer (score 1):

you could use `AWS::Serverless::Connector`.

Assuming you want to use a lambda function to start the state machine synchronization execution.

```
MyFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    ...

MyStateMachine:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
  Properties:
    ...

MyConnector:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Connector
  Properties:
    Source:
      Id: MyFunction
    Destination:
      Id: MyStateMachine
    Permissions:
    - Write
```

Answer (score 0):

Found [here](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/1855#issuecomment-744659608) that the SAM Policy template [StepFunctionsExecutionPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-template-list.html#stepfunctions-execution-policy) expect actually the name of the state machine in the parameter `StateMachineName`.

That is a little confusing given that the other policies whose parameter name  have the suffix `-Name`, expect a value that is resolved to `ARN`.

The proper way for that state machine is:

```
    - StepFunctionsExecutionPolicy:
        StateMachineName: !GetAtt SubProcessStateMachine.Name
```